# How to use unique filter with some condition in anguarljs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have few records and i want to use unique filter on specific records like to show only once if `"SubProjectId": "1"`. I am not getting any idea how i can use this filter with condition. Here is my data

```
var projects = [
 {
"DisciplineId": "240",
"DisciplineName": "General",
"SubProjectId": "1"
},
{
 "DisciplineId": "244",
"DisciplineName": "General 2",
"SubProjectId": "1"
},
{
"DisciplineId": "140",
"DisciplineName": "General etc",
"SubProjectId": "2"
},
{
"DisciplineId": "10",
"DisciplineName": "dsdsd",
"SubProjectId": "12"
},
{
 "DisciplineId": "340",
"DisciplineName": "dffd",
"SubProjectId": "2"
  } 
  ]
```

in Html:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="project in projects |
  unique: 'SubProjectId' ">{{project.SubProjectId}}</li>
</ul>
```

Result data which i want would be like that:

```
$scope.projects = [
{
"DisciplineId": "240",
"DisciplineName": "General",
"SubProjectId": "1"
 }
{
"DisciplineId": "140",
"DisciplineName": "General etc",
"SubProjectId": "2"
},
{
"DisciplineId": "10",
"DisciplineName": "dsdsd",
"SubProjectId": "12"
},
{
"DisciplineId": "340",
"DisciplineName": "dffd",
"SubProjectId": "2"
  } 
  ];
```

Comment: In the result data `DisciplineId : 340` and `DisciplineId : 140` both have  `SubProjectId:2`. How can both be displayed? They have same `SubProjectId`

Comment: Sorry for this confusion as this is not an original data. As you mentioned DisciplineId are different yes this is right as i really not need to show them anywhere so why i care of them. These object will pass on next function when i click button.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please visit the link to see the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `filter`.Just add a function which will return a filtered list containing only the first record with `SubProjectId: "1"`. Rest all the records will be same

```
    $scope.getProjects = function()
  {
    var list = [];
    var forone = false;
    console.log
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.projects.length;i++)
    {
        if($scope.projects[i].SubProjectId == "1")
      {
        if(!forone)
        {
            list.push($scope.projects[i]);
          forone = true;
        }

      }
      else
      {
        list.push($scope.projects[i]);
      }

    }
    return list;
  };
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="project in getProjects()">{{project}}</li>
  </ul>
```

**[FULL EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/04885499/6/)**

Comment: I have update question with required data which i need.

Comment: I have try it again but still "SubProjectId":"2" appear only once. I only need to show "SubProjectId":"1" one time but rest i need either they are duplicate or single.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `ng-show` or `ng-if`

```
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="project in projects ng-if="project.SubProjectId==1">
         {{project.SubProjectId}}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter as well,

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="project in projects | filter: myFilter">
     {{project.SubProjectId}}
  </li>
</ul>

$scope.myFilter = function (item) { 
    return item. SubProjectId == '1';
};
```

Comment: No. I want to filter records and show only one record which having "SubProjectId": "1". Rest will be need to show as it is either they are duplicate or not.